# TFS Release Management Artifacts Variable not available

Tags: powershell, tfs, release-management

We want to use TFS 2015.3 Release Management for Packaging/Deploying our Software.
For one of our Release Tasks we need access to the [Release Artifact Variables](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts#variables) in one of our Powershell Scripts.

But everytime we try to access one of those variables RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_[source-alias]_BUILDNUMBER for example, we receive the following error message:

[error] The term '**Release_Artifacts_[source-alias]_BUILDNUMBER**' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.

I've already tried to print out all available Environment Variables by using an inline powershell script with the following statement: Get-ChildItem Env:.
But those variables weren't there anyway..

Are there any known issues when using Release Artifact variables?

Comment: Hmm... according to [this](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts#variables) your supposed to replace the `[source-alias]` string with a valid, well, source alias of yours. They give an example: "ASPNET4.CI", which would turn into "ASPNET4_CI" in the variable name to form the complete thing named "RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_ASPNET4_CI_BUILDNUMBER".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that the Release Artifacts variables are not available for TFS on-prem; I tested the same script with VSTS and with TFS2015.3.

In VSTS release you can see the release variables in the Initialize step while in on-prem release these variables are missing:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Okay thank you for that information.
Do you know how I'm then able to copy my artifacts from my build to the let's say $(build.artifactstagingdirectory)?
So basically the question is how do I get the correct path for the build artifacts so I can work with them later on. (Zip/Deploy...)

Comment: @Mike1991 I usually use the log of the MSBuild or VisualStudio build step to identify the full path of the artifacts (e.g. C:\B\1\8\s\bin\debug\foobar.dll) then use the Copy And Publish Build Artifact build task with $(Build.SourcesDirectory)\bin\debug in the CopyRoot field

Comment: Yes but what if I need the BuildNumber of all my linked artifacts (more than one)?

Answer (score 3):

You are using the **pre-defined variables** of the form with Release Management Artifacts:

```
RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_[source-alias]_[variable-name]
```

You need to replace `[source-alias]` with the name of the alias for the artifact source included in the release definition. You can find the alias name in the **Artifacts** tab of a release definition.

[image]

Then you could use it as below：

- When used in an **Inline Script** parameter, periods in artifact
  names must be replaced with an underscore.
  `env:RELEASE_ARTIFACTS_[ScrumProject]_[BUILDNUMBER]`
- Artifact variables can also be passed as **Arguments** to tasks. In
  this case, replace the underscore with a period: 
  `Release.Artifacts.[source-alias].[variable-name]`

More details please refer this tutorial page from MSDN: [Artifacts in Microsoft Release Management](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/release/author-release-definition/understanding-artifacts#variables)

After some test, got the same result as *ds19*. Seems release artifacts is not support for TFS2015 update3 only work with VSTS for now.

---

Update

You just need to specify `build.artifactstagingdirectory` in [Publish  Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts) or [Copy and Publish Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts) step, TFS will do the thing for you. To zip the artifacts you can also use a powershell script to achieve this, more detail info you can refer this blog [Manage Artifacts with TFS Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/)

Comment: I know that I've to replace the [source-alias] but if it's really not available on premise then I've to find another workaround for that...

Comment: @Mike1991 You just need to specify `build.artifactstagingdirectory` in [Publish  Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/publish-build-artifacts) or [Copy and Publish Build Artifacts](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/steps/utility/copy-and-publish-build-artifacts) step, TFS will do the thing for you. To zip the artifacts you can also use a powershell script to achieve this, more detail info you can refer this blog [Manage Artifacts with TFS Build vNext](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2015/06/30/manage-artifacts-with-tfs-build-vnext/)